# JDO reference implementation (JDORI) download location?

Tags: java, jdo

I am trying to follow this guide: http://www.javaranch.com/journal/2004/01/IntroToJDO.html
but I need to download some .jar-files for that. The link in the guide takes me to .pdf and the rest of the links does not seem to work.

Anyone who can point me in the right direction and tell me where do get those files?
Files I need:

```
jdori.jar - JDORI specific classes
btree.jar - used by JDORI to store data 
jta.jar -Java Transaction API.
antlr.jar - Parsing classes used in the JDORI query language.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty old intro. Lots of stuff happened in the last 10 years! :)

I'd recommend you take a look @ http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/index.html
and their http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/getting_started.html guide

Comment: Those are the links I am looking for! Thank you very much!